# Gnome-manual-duplex in Gnome 3 on Arch linux

Tags: gnome3, printer

I installed the gnome-manual-duplex package from the AUR. In Ubuntu this used to add a virtual printer that you could print to.

No printer was added when I installed this package on Arch linux. The application was installed and can be run standalone but it's mostly useful when used as a printer.
How do I go about manually adding this printer to the list of available printers? It is not shown in the CUPS admin page.

The [official site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/g-manual-duplex/files/?source=navbar) says:

> Using the Gnome 3 Shell GUI:
>
> ```
> 1)      $ gnome-session-properties
>         Startup Programs -> GnomeManualDuplex -> Enable
>         [logout][login]
> 2)      Print -> GnomeManualDuplex (Virtual Printer) -> Print
> ```

But there's no package called gnome-session-properties. There's one in AUR but it is outdated.

Comment: So how do I go about solving this issue? Running `gnome-session -h` doesn't have a "properties" entry.

Comment: I added Gnome-Manual-duplex to startup items with Tweak Tool but it only launched the application at boot. On Ubuntu there's an icon in the panel always present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The issue is that the `/etc/xdg/autostart/gmd-applet-3.py.desktop` runs a python2 script whereas the default python on Arch is python 3.

I modified the EXEC line in the .desktop file from:

```
Exec=/usr/share/gnome-manual-duplex/gmd-applet-3.py run-in-tray
```

to

```
Exec=python2 /usr/share/gnome-manual-duplex/gmd-applet-3.py run-in-tray
```

and it worked perfectly.